# Replace strings using part of input match as output for all files in a directory

Tags: regex, sed, grep

- I would like to recursively replace instances of `<foo/bar.h>` with `"foo/bar.h"` (replacing `<` with `"` and `>` with `"`).
- The matching sequence may have different depths, but the root will always start with `<foo`. E.g. `<foo/baz/bar.h>` should also be replaced.

This is what I have so far, but it's missing the ability to use the middle match anything section `.*` in the output (resulting in `"foo/.*"` with is obviously incorrect)

```
grep -rl "\<foo\/.*>" ./ | xargs sed -i 's/<foo\/.*>/\"foo\/.*\"/g'
```

I'm close, but need a way to expand the `.*` in the output to actually be the match discovered in the input instead of the literal string `.*`

Examples

- `./dir1/a.cc` contains the line: `#include <foo/bar.h>` which after replacement should contain `#include "foo/bar.h"`
- `./dir1/dir2/b.h` contains the line: `#include <foo/bar/baz.h>` which after replacement should contain `#include "foo/bar/baz.h"`

Comment: Please add a small set of sample cases and the expected output (Don't make us guess). Good luck.

Comment: My apologies if this was unclear. Added two examples.

Comment: What's the recursive part about this?

Comment: @enigmativity, replace in all files + subdirs under the current dir.

Comment: @MattStokes - But it's not recursing. It's just a string that represents subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out referencing [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-complex-string-preferrably-with-regex) post:

`grep -rl "\<foo\/.*>" ./ | xargs sed -i -E 's/<foo\/(.*)>/\"foo\/\1\"/g'`

- parentheses in the first part define groups (strings in fact) that can be reused in the second part
- \1, \2, etc. in the second part are references to the i-th group captured in the first part (the numbering starts with 1)

Comment: @shellter this needs to parse over multiple input files & directories looking for the `<foo/` prefix. E.g. there may be thousands of files where `<foo/bar/baz.h>` or `<foo/bar.h>` appears 0 to many times in each file.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Glad you solved it. Removing my comment. Good luck.